# node reference to a node_collection

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have the following nodes:

- Project

  - milestones (field_collection)

    - title
    - due date
    - etc..
- Bug/Request

  - Title
  - Project (node reference)

I want to be able to link a bug to a milestone within a project. (After selecting the project.)